# >1Mbps UART core on Lattice's ICE40UP-5k FPGA?

Tags: fpga, uart, digital-communications, core

I need a UART core able to receive in the ~4-5Mbauds range (the transmitter is able to transmit up to 30Mbauds, over RS422 upstream of the FPGA), but Lattice's 16550 IP core only allows me to configure it up to 1Mbauds and the generated files are encrypted so I can't modify it myself to try it out.

I'm only starting in Verilog, using an Upduino 3.1 dev board which has a Lattice ICE40UP-5k on board. I believe the sys clock is 48MHz using the internal oscillator - though I'm not entirely sure. I guess I could bring the sys clock higher with the only available PLL if required, but 48MHz should be enough with a typical prescaler=8.

I don't need any flow control, my architecture includes two identical buffers on either side of the transmission link, which are large enough to just let the UARTs go blind at a set baudrate between writes that happen at a fixed frequency. Before each write the CPU checks the remote FIFO size -which is received back from the UART-, but it's just to accommodate imperfect baudrates.

Do you have any idea or suggestion to accomplish this?

Comment: So the device you are communicating with actually has an RS422 bus interface, correct?  If so, the speeds sound fairly reasonable given RS422 uses differential signaling.   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-422.  You'll need to oversample the serial data into your FPGA at 8 or 16x the baud rate.

Comment: That's correct. And Sounds right, c.f. my comment about a possible lead, below the one answer.

Comment: 10 or even 30 MBaud are no problem to feed into the FPGA (if signal quality is good enough), you just need a proper UART receiver code. I guess that most free cores are adaptable to at least 10 MBaud (at, say, 2x48 MHz clock frequency from a PLL). Coding a small UART is one of the typical tasks for a beginner, btw.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with UARTs > 1MHz is not the 48 MHz async clock, but the very small timing margins for FIFO flow control , and error handling with possible race conditions on the FIFO when there are framing, overrun or parity errors. It's also <= 72% efficient with start/stop/parity and latency.

Be sure to pay attention to harden timing around the FIFO logic and code for detecting when data arrives and stops.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136005/discussion-on-answer-by-tony-stewart-ee75-1mbps-uart-core-on-lattices-ice40up).

Comment: There may be hope, I'll try to implement this: https://jontio.zapto.org/hda1/fpga_intro/50%20Mbps%20UART%20in%20an%20FPGA%20my%20intro%20into%20FPGA.html. I'd appreciate if you let me know if you find anything fishy in this feat - or if you have other leads

Comment: Two thumbs up for finding that excellent writeup and the visually impaired guy who wrote it,. TL;DR My only improvement is the Rygol signals can be improved with resistors to match the source impedance to the cable and dampen with a load to the equivalent threshold.  Then use the same supply but decouple CM noise  with ferrite CM choke.  Your UTP wire may be adequate but use STP cable grounded one end if PSU's are noisy.

Comment: Then the >100 pF finger induced bit errors with cable mismatched wire inductance and source impedance much less than UTP impedance and small capacitive load can add jitter  The signal can be improved to textbook quality with resistor matching source and load to input threshold. at 50 Mbps. although I used to get away with twisted wirewrap wire which has thinner insulation and lower impedance like CMOS sources these days.  Your UTP is probably OK but might be more immune (SNR) with Rs added around 100 Ohms and 1k pullup and pulldown  load

Comment: I recall  you have to add some clever few lines to code to harden the FIFO block for speed, but I have not used the ICE40

Comment: Thanks, that's encouraging! I do agree that's tremendous work on his part anyway, I just hope it works for me. I'm planning on using a dual clock FIFO that I found online as well so I don't pay too much attention to his FIFO code.